# How to host static files of a single page webapp in firebase hosting, and deploy the web API in a different server

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a single page webapp which uses a REST API exposed through the same domain. Currently, the static files are served by the same server which exposes the REST API.

I am trying to offload the static file serving to firebase hosting. If I move the static files to firebase hosting, I have to point the DNS entries of my domain to firebase hosting, which will make the webapp to issue REST requests to firebase hosting as well.

I can update the webapp so that it will issue the REST requests to the current server address instead of firebase hosting, but it will make the requests slow since browser will use preflight requests before issuing every request due to CORS.

Does anyone know how to properly resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled with [Hosting Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config), specifically using redirects you can reference location `/foo` as your static url path and have it load content from `/bar`

```js
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Returns a permanent redirect to "/bar" for requests to "/foo" (but not "/foo/**")
  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/foo",
    "destination": "/bar",
    "type": 301
  } ]
}
```

There are other options if you need to handle cloud functions using rewrites and more, I suspect a combination will suit your needs. Please check out the [full example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#firebase-json_example) in the documentation for reference.

**Update:**

To setup an API route without cors - you can do the following

```js
app.get("/apiPath", cors({origin: false}), (req, res) => {
  /...
})
```

Comment: I prefer not to send redirects to the browser since it adds up to the latency (browser will need to send the request again to my REST endpoint after receiving the redirect, including preflight requests). Also, migrating my REST service to `cloud run` is also not an easy solution for me.

Comment: if that's the case, have you considered using a domain with a subdomain pointing to the web API? `api.myapp.com` this is fairly standard and allows you to redirect on the DNS side of events rather than relying on the intermediate of hosting itself

Comment: As soon as a different domain is involved, CORS will come into the picture and the browser will have to send preflight requests, increasing the latency, right?

Comment: you can use the no-cors flag - but most API already involves CORS from the start.
Regardless, if you want no-cors it limits your requests to HEAD, GET, and POST, and you are limited to simple headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_request_header
thankfully these are only a minor inconvenience

Comment: My API requires `Authorization` header, and some other headers, so the requests do not fall into the category of simple requests.

Comment: If you have control over the server, and you don't want cors, you can simply not use/enable it. how are you delivering your rest API? Express? Koa? other?
Cors is not always needed: https://mobilejazz.com/blog/which-security-risks-do-cors-imply/

Comment: Is it possible to disable CORS from server side? Its the browser which decides whether it needs to send the preflight requests right? My API is written with express, and I can allow CORS requests from some or all origins as I prefer in the server side, but I can't understand how I can instruct the browser to not send the preflights from the server side.

Comment: the server is in control of the CORS software logic, it's industry standard but often requires an opt-in installation through middleware.
Updating answer.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. When I invoke the above API from the javascript in the browser, browser will send a preflight request since the origin is different. Any logic I write in the server side will come into play after that, so it is too late to prevent the preflight from the browser side right? What I want to do is not just allowing CORS, but to prevent the delay introduced by preflight requests.

Comment: that only extends to caching behavior for static content such as hosting and PWA - this isn't unless you introduce proxies and gateways yourself.